# How to upload the analysis into pentaho baserver with command line

Tags: pentaho

I am using pentaho EE 5.3 . I want to upload a mondrian schema with command line. I also want to pass parameter related to DynamicSchemaParser.

I am using the below import/export utility , But that is not working.

```
./import-export.sh --import --url=XXXXX/pentaho --username=admin --password=Space2001! --file-path=/home/XXX/TRACTOrders.xml --resource-type=DATASOURCE --datasource-type=ANALYSIS --analysis-datasource=report_dw --analysis-parameters="DynamicSchemaProcessor=mondrian.security.SchemaProcessor" --analysis-parameters="UseContentChecksum=true" --overwrite=true
```

If I remove the below part it worked for me, but I want to pass parameter.

--analysis-parameters="DynamicSchemaProcessor=security.SchemaProcessor" --analysis-parameters="UseContentChecksum=true"

Could anybody please help me? How to pass parameter for analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Advanced parameters such as `UseContentChecksum` or `DynamicSchemaProcessor` should be specified in the `--analysis-datasource` switch using a semi-colon separated list:

```
--analysis-datasource=steelwheels;UseContentChecksum=true;DynamicSchemaProcessor=com.transverse.bleep.mondrian.security.TractTenantedDynamicSchemaProcessor
```